# Rave Reports and EAN128 Barcode

Tags: delphi, barcode, rave-reports

I am trying to print an EAN128 barcode in Rave reports.  According to the help I should be able to use the code128 component, and add the FNC1 to it.  I just cannot get this to work. Can anyone please help me.

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same problem today. The FNC1 character in Rave is ñ (n tilde, ascii 241). Just put that at the front of your code and it should be correctly recognized as EAN128. Worked for me in Rave Reports 5.1.

Comment: Just to point out that an EAN-128 (formally GS1-128) may contain "attribute data" alongside the GTIN-14, i.e. additional Application Identifiers besides (01). Many of these AIs are defined to be variable length and these require separating from subsequent fields using an FNC1 character - presumably with Rave Reports in the same way as inserting the leading FNC1.